# Nodejs Sequeslize error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, phpmyadmin, sequelize.js

I am new to sequelize, mysql and phpmyadmin. I am trying to connect to my remote database but i get the following error:

> Uncaught Exception: 500 - connect ECONNREFUSED xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx, Stack: SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED xx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx

I checked out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266221/node-js-mysql-error-connect-econnrefused) and various other solution on Stackoverflow but it didnt solve my problem.

database.ts

```
import { Sequelize } from "sequelize";
import { DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_USER } from "../config";
export const DB = new Sequelize(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, {
  host: DB_HOST,
  dialect: "mysql",
  logging: false,
  typeValidation: true,
  dialectOptions: {
    supportBigNumbers: true,
    bigNumberStrings: true,
  },
  define: {
    charset: "utf8mb4",
    collate: "utf8mb4_unicode_ci",
    createdAt: "created_at",
    updatedAt: "updated_at",
    deletedAt: "deleted_at",
    paranoid: true,
    underscored: true,
  },
  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000,
  },
});
```

Comment: are you sure that there is a mysql in your host

Comment: @nbk Yes, there is.

Comment: the error message is clearly saying with your configuration, it doesn't so check every part of the connection string host port if they are correct

Comment: This kinda looks like a firewall issue.  Are you able to connect to the database in question from the computer that is running your `sequelize` code via some other means?  In other words, can you connect via [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) or the [MySQL command line](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html) from the computer running your code?

Comment: The problem is with your mysql server, you may have to check if it accept connection from your ip address, or grant access to any host if it is a development environment, which Operating System is your mysql server installed?

Comment: @akisoft my operating system is ubuntu 16.0.How do i check if mysql server will accept connection from my ip address?