# Error connecting to database: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 126.181.11.232:3306 in linux server

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I had completed my website (React+node+express+mysql). and i want to host my whole website in linux server.
i successfully created the database in mysql but i encountered some error.

**I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30266221/node-js-mysql-error-connect-econnrefused) already. it didn't work for me**

**My error is**

```
Error connecting to database: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 185.181.11.232:3306
```

**I created my database like this**

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "***",
    database: "attendance"
});

connection.connect(function (error) {
    if (error) {
        console.error('Error connecting to database: ' + error.stack);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Connected to database with ID ' + connection.threadId);
});
```

**Please give me some suggestion how can i correct this**

I am expecting to output like this `Connected to database with ID`

Comment: Is the server yours or a shared one?

Comment: If the new server is a shared server they are not going to let you use the MySQL `root` account. There will be something in your panel telling you how to create a MySQL user or the one they create for you, you will have to change the code to use that

Comment: @RiggsFolly it does not even get to authenticating with a mysql user, connection refused means that the code cannot even reach mysql.

Comment: Usually `localhost` connects using a Unix-domain socket, not a network socket.

Comment: actually in my cpanel nothing is given about the database. so i am really confused.